# Keep max date in column when pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this data that i want to pivot. It all goes well as long as i don't include the datewhat differs on some rows. I would like to keep the highest date for each set of `idAnalyseItem`.
My query looks like this for the moment, and i struggle with how the date part of it fits in.

```
WITH Analyser AS (
    SELECT ElementItems.idAnalyseItem as Analyse, ESymbol as Symbol, EIValue as Verdi
    FROM ElementItems
)
SELECT * FROM Analyser

PIVOT(
    MAX(Verdi) FOR Symbol IN ([Justert],[Produkt Type],[Start Time],[Stopp Time],[Dunger],[Våtvekt],[Vann],[Fe-tot],[Fe-Mag],[Svovel],[P],[SiO2],[MnO],[Al2O3],[CaO],[1,19],[0,841],[0,425],[0,212],[0,125],[0,106],[0,075],[0,063],[0,045],[0,02])
) AS PivotTable 

ORDER BY Analyse DESC
```

This is my dataset. Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

[image: My dataset (or at least some of it)]

Comment: the dates are not unique? you want to return more than one row with the highest date? You want to look into partition by. `MAX(EIDatetime) OVER (PARTITION BY EIDatetime) as date`

Comment: Dates can span over several days depending on when they do the different analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query like following, to get the `MAX(EIDateTime)` for all the rows belongs to a `idAnalyseItem`

```
;WITH Analyser AS (
    SELECT ElementItems.idAnalyseItem as Analyse, ESymbol as Symbol, EIValue as Verdi, MAX(EIDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY ElementItems.idAnalyseItem) EIDateTime 
    FROM ElementItems
)
SELECT * FROM Analyser
PIVOT(
    MAX(Verdi) FOR Symbol IN ([Justert],[Produkt Type],[Start Time],[Stopp Time],[Dunger],[Våtvekt],[Vann],[Fe-tot],[Fe-Mag],[Svovel],[P],[SiO2],[MnO],[Al2O3],[CaO],[1,19],[0,841],[0,425],[0,212],[0,125],[0,106],[0,075],[0,063],[0,045],[0,02])
) AS PivotTable 

ORDER BY Analyse DESC
```

Same thing can be done using `GROUP BY` like following.

```
;WITH Analyser AS (
    SELECT ElementItems.idAnalyseItem as Analyse, ESymbol as Symbol, EIValue as Verdi, MAX(EIDateTime) as EIDateTime 
    FROM ElementItems
    GROUP BY idAnalyseItem,ESymbol,EIValue
)
SELECT * FROM Analyser
PIVOT(
    MAX(Verdi) FOR Symbol IN ([Justert],[Produkt Type],[Start Time],[Stopp Time],[Dunger],[Våtvekt],[Vann],[Fe-tot],[Fe-Mag],[Svovel],[P],[SiO2],[MnO],[Al2O3],[CaO],[1,19],[0,841],[0,425],[0,212],[0,125],[0,106],[0,075],[0,063],[0,045],[0,02])
) AS PivotTable 

ORDER BY Analyse DESC
```

Comment: This query gives me `Incorrect syntax near 'order'`

Comment: @jared I have updated the answer, can you have a look

Comment: I just removed the `ORDER BY`in the partitioning and it worked like intended! Thank you for the group by suggestion as well.